# EF Proxies and complex data structures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, proxy, iqueryable

**The Problem Domain**

Say I have an entity that looks something like this ...

```
public class HierarchyObject
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Parent")]
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public virtual HierarchyObject Parent { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<HierarchyObject> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Ok now i'm using EF so I can simply do something like ...

```
var ctx = new MyContext();
var getAll = ctx.HierarchyObjects.AsQueryable();
```

Now lets say I add permissions to these objects so certain users can only do basic CRUD operations on a subset of these objects I might now do something like ...

```
getAll = getAll().Where(o => o.Permissions.Any(p => p.Read && UserId == currentUserId));
```

This returns only the items that the user can access.

Now I want to expose this behind a queryable endpoint, lets say OData.

OData will allow me to write a URL like this ...

> ~/Api/HierarchyObject?$Expand=Children

... having done that I just broke my security as the EF proxy does not know about my permission rule as the result would be "All objects I have access to and their children" and the real question should have been "all objects I can access expand in to all their children that I have access to".

**So my question is**

Is there a way to tell EF that when crawling that Children Property it should also apply a where clause ...

```
o.Children = o.Children.Where(o => o.Permissions.Any(p => p.Read && UserId == currentUserId));
```

... and apply that rule on all my Heirarchy objects any time it "proxies" one of them?

**More details**

I found this:

[How can I dynamically customize a POCO proxy in EF 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464669/how-can-i-dynamically-customize-a-poco-proxy-in-ef-4)

All well and good, ssays what i'm trying to do is impossible in EF4 but i'm using EF6 so I figured that Microsoft / someone else perhaps may have foudn a way round this by now allowing a decent way to intercept / override the proxy creation process in some way perhaps using the type IDbSet as the driver for a rule hook that lets you define some proxying rules in some way for relational crawls but I haven't found anything yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I went the wrong way about this.
Instead of proxying the object to prevent relatinship crawling I found I can restrict returned entities by type using EF filters.

There's a bunch of packages for this on Nuget that extend the EF functionality essentially giving a context sensitive "cut of the db" before running any of the business logic code on top of it.